# Sum of a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n3^nx^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How to evaluate the sum of the series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n \cdot 3^n\cdot x^n)$$

I have tried with integration and derivation, but that doesn't lead to any intuitive (known) series.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_to_infinite_terms

Comment: HINT: Differentiate $\sum_{n\ge 0}(3x)^n$ and then multiply by $x$.

Comment: This post might be useful: [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/30732) And perhaps also some of the questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30732).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(3x)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(3x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(3x)^{n+1}=3x\left(S+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3x)^n\right)
=3x\left(S+\frac1{1-3x}\right).$$

You can deduce $$S=\frac{3x}{(1-3x)^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Denote $H=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}nr^n$ whih $|r|<1.$ Then: $$H=r+2r^2+3r^3+4r^4+\cdots,$$ $$rH=r^2+2r^3+3r^4+4r^5+\cdots,$$ $$H-Hr=H(1-r)=r+r^2+r^3+\cdots=-1+(1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots)$$ $$=-1+\frac{1}{1-r}=\frac{r}{1-r}\Rightarrow H=\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}.$$ For $r=3x,$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n3^nx^n=\frac{3x}{(1-3x)^2},\quad (|x|<1/3).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is  a   variation  using differentiation (see comment from @BrianMScott)

> We obtain for $|x|<\frac{1}{3}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty n3^nx^n&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(3x\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=3x\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(3x)^{n-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(3x)^n\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-3x}-1\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{3x}{(1-3x)^2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we start with $n=1$ since the term with $n=0$ is zero.
- In (2) we factor out $3x$.
- In (3) we use the differential operator and respect the chain rule (factor $3$).
- In (4) we use the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* formula and subtract $1$ since the index $n$ starts from $1$.